# Using np.where but maintaining exisitng values if condition is False

Tags: numpy, pandas, where-clause

I like np.where, but have never fully got to grip with it.

I have a dataframe lets say it looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy import nan as NA
DF = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [ 3, 0, 1, 0, 1, 14, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   'b' : [ 3, 0, 1, 0, 1, 14, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   'c' : [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   'd' : [5, 1, 2 ,1, 1 ,22, 30, 1, 0, 0, 0]})
```

Now what I want to do is replace the 0 values with NaN values when all row values are zero. Critically I want to maintain whatever other values are in the row in the cases where all row values are not zero.

I want to do something like this:

```
cols = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
condition = (DF[cols] == 0).all(axis=1)
for col in cols:
    DF[col] = np.where(condition, NA, ???)
```

I put the ??? to indicate that I do not know what value to place there if the condition is False, I just want to preserve whatever is there already. Is this possible with np.where, or should I use another technique?

Comment: Perhaps this is in fact the best way? " `DF.loc[DF[(DF[cols] == 0).all(axis = 1)].index, cols] = NA`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is a `pandas.Series` method (`where` incidentally) for exactly this kind of task.  It seems a little backward at first, but from the documentation.

> Series.where(cond, other=nan, inplace=False, axis=None, level=None,
>   try_cast=False, raise_on_error=True)
>
> Return an object of same shape as
>   self and whose corresponding entries are from self where cond is True
>   and otherwise are from other.

So, your example would become

```
cols = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
condition = (DF[cols] == 0).all(axis=1)
for col in cols:
    DF[col].where(~condition, np.nan, inplace=True)
```

But, if all you're trying to do is replace rows of all zeros for specific set of columns with `NA`, you could do this instead

```
DF.loc[condition, cols] = NA
```

**EDIT**

To answer your original question, `np.where` follows the same [broadcasting rules](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) as other array operations so you would replace `???` with `DF[col]`, changing your example to:

```
cols = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
condition = (DF[cols] == 0).all(axis=1)
for col in cols:
    DF[col] = np.where(condition, NA, DF[col])
```

Answer (score 4):

Proposed solutions work but for numpy array there is a simpler way without using DataFrame.

A solution would be :
`np_array[np.where(condition)] = value_of_condition_true_rows`

Answer (score 1):

To keep original values, use the following

```
#replace all if value greater than 3
arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,3])
# condition, if true -> change to , if false -> the value to be kept  
x=np.where(arr>3,100,arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
    array_binary = np.where(array[i]<threshold,0,1)
    array_sparse = np.multiply(array_binary,np.ones_like(array))
```

do an element-wise multiplication of the binary array and an array of ones using np.multiply. Hence, the non-zero elements will be recovered/maintained.
array_sparse is the sparse version of array